# git rebase -i HEAD~all commits count

Tags: git

I have 3 commits. When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~3` it gives me

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~3
```

Though, if I try `git rebase -i HEAD~2` this succesfully opens last 2 commits in editor.

Question: Why  `git rebase -i HEAD~3` gives error in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three commits.  They have unique hash IDs, but I can't guess what they are, and besides, they're big and ugly / unwieldy anyway, so let's just call the three commits `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`.

The current branch name (probably `master`) holds the actual hash ID of existing commit `C3`.  The name `HEAD` holds the branch name.  Commit `C3` holds the hash ID of commit `C2`, and commit `C2` holds the hash ID of commit `C1`.  Commit `C1` is the very first commit, so it holds no earlier-commit hash ID.

Whenever something—a name, or a commit—holds a hash ID, we say that the thing *points to* that commit.  So we can draw this series of commits like this:

```
C1 <-C2 <-C3   <--master (HEAD)
```

When you run:

```
git rebase -i <expression>
```

Git has to turn the *`expression`* into the hash ID of a commit.  `HEAD` means: *find the commit named by `HEAD`*.  `HEAD` names `master` which names commit `C3`, so this means *commit `C3`*.

The `~` suffix notation works by traveling backwards along the arrows, one at a time, from the commit found by the first part.  So `HEAD~1` means: *First, find the commit named by `HEAD`—that's `C3`—*and then step back once*.  That gets us to `C2`, so `HEAD~1` arrives at `C2` and means `git rebase hash-of-C2`.

Try this with `HEAD~2`: start at `C3`, then step back along the arrows twice.  Where you do you up?  At `C1`, right?

Now try it with `HEAD~3`: starting at `C3`, step back three times.  What happens?  When you're at `C1`, what will you step back to?

(You should now understand why this does not work.  The error message here is not great: it should probably say something more like `HEAD~3 does not exist`.)

#### What if you really want to copy all three commits?

Since there's no way to step any further back once your reach `C1`, `git rebase` literally can't take any direct instruction to copy all three commits.  (Remember that `git rebase` means *copy some set of commits, then adjust the branch name to point to the last-copied commit.*)  So `git rebase -i` has the flag `--root` to handle this particular case: it means keep stepping back, listing commits to copy, until you can't step back any more, and *include that first commit*.  Then copy all of those commits.  (The first copy becomes a new root commit: a new commit with no parent.)